# angular 2: prevent form fields to become valid as long as async-validator is still running

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Short thing: I have input fields in a reactive form, which are all validated by several sync-validators (min-value, required and so on).

Additionally I have a debounced validator on the form itself. This validator might set several input field to invalid. In this case the input fields flicker between valid (green border) and invalid (red border).

This behaviour is due to the fact that the sync-validator will render the input-fields as valid, but then 250ms later the async-validator will declare those inputs invalid again.

So basically I have flickering input-fields with every single keystore (as long as I type slow enough)

**Solutions:** ?

What I need is to have all validators executing in the same tick (after waiting for the debounce-time). Even when I debounce all validators individually by the same time, there will be a slight flickering in the border-color.

Or I could have all inputs on the form debounced by 250ms, so that all validators and models behind the form will get the information only after a debounce-time of 250ms. Applying debouceTime(250= to valueChanges does not do the trick, since the valdator will already have done their job.

Comment: This [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6895) about how to use debounce with async validators might help you.

Comment: As you didn't provide any example I believe your IF is wrong, you probably need to check the control status for PENDING, controls that have an async validator have this additional status, which is hidden somewhere in the documentation and I cannot find it right now :))

Comment: [Here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#control-status-css-classes) are also the CSS classes that you have available and you can see that there is a `.ng-pending` which is not documented

Comment: I upvoted all your comments, because every single one of them was *very* helpful! Why dont you put them in form of an answer so I can upvote them for real. Again, thanks! You really helped me with this! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use `[diabled]="!form.valid"` instead of `[disabled]="form.invalid"` because the form is in a `pending` state and thus not invalid.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is going to work for you but I fix my problem with something similar to this making use of from.pending status. When you make an async validation, the form._status changes to 'PENDING', and form.pending = true, so I disable my input like:

`[disabled]="seedForm.invalid || seedForm.pending"`

avoiding the 250 ms of seedForm.invalid = false when the async validation is running.

Hope it works for you.